# Using ColorFunction Rasterizes the plot

Tags: plotting, color, vector, mathematica-online, rasterize

When I make a simple plot using ColorFunction, the Mathematica rasterize the plot. Is anyone else having this issue? Does anyone know a way to avoid this?

```
Plot[E^{-x, -1.2 x, -2.4 x}, {x, 0, 5}, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["Rainbow"]]
```

[image: Non Rasterized]
[image: Rasterized]

The one that's rasterized looks pretty ugly.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. In Mathematica 12.3 on MacOS  plot is still in vector form as far as I can tell. I can grab curves for instances. cf https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWf5f.jpg

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and Mathematica 12.2 but my plot is rasterized and its not a vector anymore. I guess MacOS doesn't have this issue.

Comment: What can you not do with this plot once it is rasterized? Please include an example task that you can do without the `ColorFunction` included.

Comment: You mean, it rasterizes when you `Export` it? I can confirm the @chris observation. Everything is fine on macOS.

Comment: No. It generates a Rasterized plot even before saving it. I think it's Windows issue. Same thing happens on Linux.